# Meaning of 中継で観る

Tags: meaning, words, expressions

Context: a mangaka is talking about the story of the manga she draws and its writer.

> 山口先生の執筆作業を中継で観たいです！

I am not sure what this sentence means, in particular 中継で観たい. I found on dictionaries that 中継 has to do with broadcasting. Does she want the manga to be broadcasted on TV? So, in practice, she wants it to become an anime? Thank you for your help!

Comment: 中継 means "relay broadcast", and 観たい is "viewing" - lit. viewing a relay broadcast. But it not totally turns "her manga will become anime" - it most likely "her works currently being relayed on a TV broadcast".

Comment: ^ `観たい is viewing` 観たい is "want to watch", no?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Please, do not post your answer as a comment, *especially when you're not 100% confident*. Answers should be in the place where other users can both upvote and downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

中継で is "live". The original meaning of 中継 is "relay" (i.e., passing information to another device without modifying it), but many people understand this word simply as "live (broadcasting)". It's very similar to 生放送, but 中継 refers to live broadcasting of something happening outside of a studio.

[image]

In this context, this 中継 almost certainly refers to internet live streaming (Ustream, YouTube live, etc.). Live-streaming someone drawing a picture (usually while chatting) is popular at least among Japanese manga fans. See [some of these videos](https://freshlive.tv/tags/%E3%81%8A%E7%B5%B5%E6%8F%8F%E3%81%8D) to get the feeling of what they look like. The object of 観たい is the mangaka's 執筆作業 (i.e., their drawing process), not their final product.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the sentence I provided, the speaker is the mangaka, while 山口先生 is the author of the story. Does it make sense to watch a live streaming of someone writing a story? I could understand someone drawing, but not just writing...

Comment: @Marco Oh, live streaming of someone writing a story with a keyboard? That's definitely uncommon, but I cannot think of another reasonable interpretation. 執筆 is both for manga and novels.

Answer (score 1):

> Context: a mangaka is talking about the story of the manga she draws and its writer.
>
> > 山口先生の執筆作業を中継で観たいです！
>
> I am not sure what this sentence means, in particular 中継で観たい.
>   Does she want the manga to be broadcasted on TV?

(I don't know whose word it is, but it's ok.)
It says 執筆作業を観たい. It's saying the speaker wants to see the writer working on her (his?) work.

Now, I believe it doesn't really matter what 中継 is. Do we think this is the occasion when we matter how the picture has been brought to us? 中継 alone, we can't really tell what it's saying. Maybe it's a jargon used in the broadcasting industry, but fortunately we don't really need to know what that is here.

But at least we can tell that the speaker is saying s/he wants to see 山口先生 working on her/his work through some kind of media. Maybe implying the speaker can't ask for staying at the room where 山口先生 is working.